# How to update table contents using generator.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1

I use Symfony 1.3 at work. Displaying lists using admin generator and modifying generator.yml but I cannot update the lists. （id asc → desc etc..）

I tried cache clear command as below.

`php symfony cc`

I expect to update the table when modifying generator.yml.
If I try in the wrong way, I'd like to know how to update the table in the right way.

Comment: What have you tried (please add generator.yml code snippet) What have you put in generator.yml under `config > list > sort` ?